# table2CSV.js - Works wonderful, but having issues specifying which table to export

Tags: php, jquery, export-to-csv

I'm having trouble exporting using table2CSV.js when there are multiple tables on the page.

The first one will work correctly, but any other buttons will export a blank file.  Any ideas?  If you need more info please advise.

I want to add that it's always the first table on the page that works correctly...

Please review single the call (JS):

```
function getCSVData(tableName){
    var csv_value=$(tableName).table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
    $("#csv_text").val(csv_value);
}
```

And the HTML form buttons to call the JS (there are a few on the page):

```
<form action="getCSV.php" method ="post" > 
    <input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text">
    <input type="hidden" name="fileName" id="fileName" value="<?php echo($fileName); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Download Table 0" onclick="getCSVData('table#detail0')">
</form>


<form action="getCSV.php" method ="post" > 
    <input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text">
    <input type="hidden" name="fileName" id="fileName" value="<?php echo($fileName); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Download Table 1" onclick="getCSVData('table#detail1')">
</form>

<form action="getCSV.php" method ="post" > 
    <input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text">
    <input type="hidden" name="fileName" id="fileName" value="<?php echo($fileName); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Download Table 2" onclick="getCSVData('table#detail2')">
</form>
```

Here is a few table open tags for reference as well:

For reference, here's the getCSV.php file

```
<?php
    $file = $_REQUEST['fileName'];
    $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
    header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");

    $csv_output=stripcslashes($_REQUEST['csv_text']);
    print $csv_output;
    exit;   

?>
```

For reference, here's the table2CSV.js code:

```
jQuery.fn.table2CSV = function(options) {
    var options = jQuery.extend({
        separator: ',',
        header: [],
        delivery: 'popup' // popup, value
    },
    options);

    var csvData = [];
    var headerArr = [];
    var el = this;

    //header
    var numCols = options.header.length;
    var tmpRow = []; // construct header avalible array

    if (numCols > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            tmpRow[tmpRow.length] = formatData(options.header[i]);
        }
    } else {
        $(el).filter(':visible').find('th').each(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') tmpRow[tmpRow.length] = formatData($(this).html());
        });
    }

    row2CSV(tmpRow);

    // actual data
    $(el).find('tr').each(function() {
        var tmpRow = [];
        $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') tmpRow[tmpRow.length] = formatData($(this).html());
        });
        row2CSV(tmpRow);
    });
    if (options.delivery == 'popup') {
        var mydata = csvData.join('\n');
        return popup(mydata);
    } else {
        var mydata = csvData.join('\n');
        return mydata;
    }

    function row2CSV(tmpRow) {
        var tmp = tmpRow.join('') // to remove any blank rows
        // alert(tmp);
        if (tmpRow.length > 0 && tmp != '') {
            var mystr = tmpRow.join(options.separator);
            csvData[csvData.length] = mystr;
        }
    }
    function formatData(input) {
        // replace " with “
        var regexp = new RegExp(/["]/g);
        var output = input.replace(regexp, "“");
        //HTML
        var regexp = new RegExp(/\<[^\<]+\>/g);
        var output = output.replace(regexp, "");
        if (output == "") return '';
        return '"' + output + '"';
    }
    function popup(data) {
        var generator = window.open('', 'csv', 'height=400,width=600');
        generator.document.write('<html><head><title>CSV</title>');
        generator.document.write('</head><body >');
        generator.document.write('<textArea cols=70 rows=15 wrap="off" >');
        generator.document.write(data);
        generator.document.write('</textArea>');
        generator.document.write('</body></html>');
        generator.document.close();
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 for a clear question with all the supporting code. However, I'm wondering why you don't just post JSON code to the PHP server, and then use PHP's CSV functionality?

Comment: @Spudley I've tried it all =).  This has been the best script I've ever used without having to write additional code.  I could implement this quick JS/jQuery script on ANY website that has correctly formatted tables, and this thing spits out a perfect CSV every time.

Comment: I moved that script to GitHub: https://github.com/rubo77/table2CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working for the second and the third table because you give the same id to all your 3 inputs (hidden) in your forms.

```
<input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text">
```

An ID should be **UNIQUE**

If you have multiple HTMLElement with the same ID, when retrieve it in Javascript, it will retrieve the first found from the begining. So it will always retrieve the one from the first form.

Change your inputs in each form for :

```
<input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text_1" />

<input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text_2" />

<input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text_3" />
```

And then, modifiy your function:

```
function getCSVData(tableName, num){
    var csv_value=$(tableName).table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
    $("#csv_text_" + num).val(csv_value);
}
```

Finally update your calls:

```
<input type="submit" value="Download Table 0" onclick="getCSVData('table#detail0', '0')">

<input type="submit" value="Download Table 0" onclick="getCSVData('table#detail1', '1')">

<input type="submit" value="Download Table 0" onclick="getCSVData('table#detail2', '2')">
```

Personnal opinion: It seems a little bit useless to send all the content of the table, just to add a file attachment header thanks to the PHP server. You are using the network to send a data that will be re-sent to you without any modification (just for header addition).

If I have to do such a process, I would just send a simple GET request to a specific PHP script that will send me the correct header, and then, generate the CSV content, retrieving the data from the database.